# Idiomatic way to accept owned and referenced iterables?

Tags: rust, iterator, traits, ownership

Consider this rust code:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d6f2075a8872305334a8ba513241950b

```rust
fn main() {
    let v: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    // This works, of course.
    println!("{}", foo(&v));
    
    // Now let's create an "extra conversion" step:
    let vs: Vec<&str> = vec!["1", "2", "3"];
    
    // We want to "stream" straight from this vec. Let's create an 
    // iterator that converts:
    let converting_iterator = vs.iter().map(|s| s.parse::<i32>().unwrap());
    
    // This does not work
    println!("{}", foo(converting_iterator));
}

fn foo<'a>(it: impl IntoIterator<Item=&'a i32>) -> i32 {
    it.into_iter().sum()
}
```

I understand why the second line doesn't work. It creates an iterator over `i32`, not `&i32`. I can't just slap a `&` into the closure, because that would attempt to reference a temporary value.

What I'd be curious about though is if there is *any* way to write `foo` in such a way that it can deal with both types of iterables? If I were to just add the `.sum()` to the end of creating the `converting_iterator`, it would just work. So I feel that there should be *some* way to "intercept" the result (i.e. the converting iterator), pass *that* to something, and have *that something* call `.sum` on it.

Maybe something with `Borrow` or `AsRef`, but I couldn't figure that out from the documentation of those traits.

Comment: Why not just change `foo` to accept an `impl Iterator<Item=i32>`?

Comment: Because then the first line doesn't work anymore, the one with `foo(&v)`.

Comment: But maybe there's a misunderstanding on my end about what's idiomatic. I'd assume that in general, for function parameters, if you don't _need_ to take ownership, then it's "nicer" to use a borrow.

Comment: Since `i32` is is `Copy` type, I would probably just make the caller do the conversion: `foo(v.iter().copied())`. Are you looking for a solution that works for non-copy types as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more broad answer is to use the [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) trait to accept references and non-references generically:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn foo<'a, T: Borrow<i32>>(it: impl IntoIterator<Item = T>) -> i32 {
    it.into_iter().map(|t| *t.borrow()).sum()
}
```

It is unfortunately not as nice as [PitaJ's answer](/a/74661660/) since `.sum()` is already fine with both references and non-references, but doesn't handle `impl Borrow`, so we have to introduce a `.map()` to get the integers out of the potentially-borrowed type. But this is a trick to use if your function was different.

This is a pattern seen in other questions:

- [How to write a function that accepts a `Vec` of borrowed or owned elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73839107)
- [Can one do generics over references and non-references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205437)

Answer (score 1):

For sum in particular, the following works:

```rust
fn foo<Item>(it: impl IntoIterator<Item=Item>) -> i32
where i32: Sum<Item>
{
    it.into_iter().sum()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I guess whatever operation I want, I'll need the appropriate trait bound.